# AWS Athena - UPDATE table rows using SQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, parquet-dataset

I am newbie to AWS ecosystem. I am creating an application which queries data using AWS Athena. Data is transformed from JSON into parquet using AWS Glue and stored in S3.

Now use case is to update that parquet data using SQL.

can we update underlying parquet data using AWS Athena SQL command?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to use `UPDATE` in Amazon Athena.

Amazon Athena is a **query engine**, not a database. It performs queries on data that is stored in Amazon S3. It **reads** those files, but it does *not* modify or update those files. Therefore, it cannot 'update' a table.

The closest capability is using `CREATE TABLE AS` to create a *new* table. You can provide a `SELECT` query that uses data from other tables, so you could effectively modify information and store it in a new table, and tell it to use Parquet for that new table. In fact, this is an excellent way to convert data from other formats into Snappy-compressed Parquet files (with partitioning, if you wish).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how data is stored in Athena, you *can* update it using SQL `UPDATE` statmements. See *[Updating Iceberg table data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-iceberg-updating-iceberg-table-data.html#querying-iceberg-update)* and *[Using governed tables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/lf-governed-tables.html)*.